# Which excel chart to use for score distribution per label?

Tags: excel, charts, distribution

I have a small table of 300 rows, 2 columns - score and label. The label is 0 or 1, the score is between 0 and 100. I want to see the difference in the distributions. I want to know if label 0 is more likely to get a low score. Which chart would do the best job here?
Ideally, I would want to see the dots of each label in a different color and hopefully see blue dots on one side and red dots on the other (if the data is fantastic)

Thanks!

Edit: This is an example of what I was hoping to get (taken from google images after googling "ggplot 2 groups")

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnwhN.png)

Comment: Hi Tomer, welcome to SO! SO is about asking **specific** and **answerable** questions for others to review and help you with. We are not here to write a program for you or suggest which tools you should be using. If you are able to post whatever attempts you have made in a clear and concise way, I'm sure someone will be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can really use any chart to show that data if you truly only want to see the distribution of label scores.